# How would I approach Parallel Arrays to store different types of information in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop, parallel-arrays

I have the following task which is that:

There may be up to ten teams.  Parallel Arrays are used to store the team Names, as well as to keep track of the number of Wins, Overtime Losses, and Points.  After the result for the last team is entered, the program outputs a summary of each team's record in the opposite order to which they were entered.

Note: "W" is worth 2 points, "L" is worth 0 points, "O" is worth 1 point

Sample input:

```
   3 //Option number 
Toronto //phrase
   W //letters that loop in a while loop
   W
   L
   O
   W
   O
   W
   N //To close the while loop, "N" is entered
Montreal
   L
   L
   O
   L
   L
   W
   L
   L
   N // To close the while loop, "N" is entered
Vancouver
   W
   W
   O
   O
   L
   N //To close the while loop, "N" is entered
Winnipeg
   L
   L
   L
   W
   O
   O
   W
   W
   W
   W
   W
   W
   W
   Q //To close the while loop and get all the results, "Q" is entered
```

Sample output **(It outputs the results in the opposite order)**:

```
Team W O L P //States that first, Team and then Wins, Overtime, Losses, and then points. "W" is 2 points, "O" is 1 point, and "L" is 0 point
Winnipeg 8 2 3 18
Vancouver 2 2 1 6
Montreal 1 1 6 3
Toronto 4 2 1 10
```

**I did a similar task with options 2, that requires no use of arrays, now this is options 3, which requires the use of Parallel Arrays Only**

Options 2 Code:

```
else if (option == 2){
            int pointsW = 0;
            int pointsL = 0;
            int pointsO = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            int totalpoints = 0;
            String phrase = keyboard.next();
            while(go){
                String letter = keyboard.next();
                    if (letter.equals("W")){
                    pointsW+=2;
                    }
                    else if (letter.equals("L")){
                    pointsL+=0;
                    }
                    else if (letter.equals("O")){
                    pointsO+=1;
                    }
                    counter++;
                    if (letter.equals("N")){
                        totalpoints = pointsW + pointsL + pointsO;
                        counter--;
                        go = false;
                }
            }
            int counter2 = 0;
            int totalpoints2 = 0;
            int pointsW2 = 0;
            int pointsL2 = 0;
            int pointsO2 = 0;
            String phrase2 = keyboard.next();
                while (go2){
                    String letter = keyboard.next();
                    if (letter.equals("W")){
                    pointsW2+=2;
                    }
                    else if (letter.equals("L")){
                    pointsL2+=0;
                    }
                    else if (letter.equals("O")){
                    pointsO2+=1;
                    }
                    counter2++;
                    if (letter.equals("Q")){
                        counter2--;
                        totalpoints2 = pointsW2 + pointsL2 + pointsO2;
                        go2 = false;
                        }
                    }
                            System.out.println(phrase + " has played "+counter+" games and has earned "+totalpoints+" points");
                            System.out.println(phrase2 + " has played "+counter2+" games and has earned "+totalpoints2+" points");
                    if (totalpoints > totalpoints2){
                        int wins = totalpoints - totalpoints2;
                            System.out.println(phrase + " is in first place by "+ wins + " points");
                    }else{
                        int wins2 = totalpoints2 - totalpoints;
                            System.out.println(phrase2 + " is in first place by "+ wins2 + " points");
            }
        }
```

How would I incorporate Parallel Arrays into Options 3 with the same idea of options 2? I'm really new to learning about parallel arrays and couldn't get any help finding information online about it.

**UPDATE**

```
else if (option == 3){
            int teams = 10;
            String phrase[] = new String[teams];
            int wins[] = new int [teams];
            int overtime[] = new int [teams];
            int loss[] = new int [teams];
            int points[] = new int [teams];
            int x;
                for (x = 0; x < teams; x++){
                    phrase[x] = keyboard.next();
                    while (go3){
                        String letter = keyboard.next();
                        if (letter.equals("W")){
                            wins[x]++;
                        }
                        else if (letter.equals("L")){
                            loss[x]++;
                        }
                        else if (letter.equals("O")){
                            overtime[x]++;
                        }
                        else if (letter.equals("N") || letter.equals("Q")){
                        points[x] = wins[x]*2+overtime[x];
                        go3 = false;
                        if (letter.equals("Q")){
                            break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                    System.out.println("Team W O L P");
                        for (int i = x; i >= 0; i--){
                            System.out.println(phrase[i] + " " + wins[i] + " " + overtime[i] + " " + loss[i] + " " + points[i]);
         }
       }
    }
 }
```

ERROR I GET:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need arrays for names, wins, losses, overtimes and points. However, when you learn more, you will better manage it by creating a custom type say, `Game` which will have attributes like, `name`, and a `List` type attribute for recording wins, losses, overtimes etc.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Standings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter option: ");
        int option = keyboard.nextInt();

        // Number of teams
        int teams = 10;

        // Array for team names
        String[] teamNames = new String[teams];

        // Array to record total wins for each team
        int[] wins = new int[teams];

        // Array to record total overtimes for each team
        int[] overtimes = new int[teams];

        // Array to record total losses for each team
        int[] losses = new int[teams];

        // Array for team points
        int[] points = new int[teams];

        // Variable to be used as a counter for the number of games
        int x;

        // The program will exit when exit = true
        boolean exit = false;

        if (option == 3) {
            System.out.println("[Enter N to end the game for a team or Q to terminate the program]");
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");
            // Input and calculation
            for (x = 0; x < teams && !exit; x++) {
                String letter;
                boolean go = true;

                System.out.print("Enter the name of team " + (x + 1) + ": ");
                teamNames[x] = keyboard.next();
                while (go) {
                    System.out.print("Enter W/L/O for match result: ");
                    letter = keyboard.next();

                    if (letter.equals("W")) {
                        wins[x]++;
                    } else if (letter.equals("O")) {
                        overtimes[x]++;
                    } else if (letter.equals("L")) {
                        losses[x]++;
                    } else if (letter.equals("N") || letter.equals("Q")) {
                        points[x] = wins[x] * 2 + overtimes[x];
                        go = false;
                        if (letter.equals("Q")) {
                            exit = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Output
            System.out.println("Team W O L P");
            for (int i = x - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                System.out
                        .println(teamNames[i] + " " + wins[i] + " " + overtimes[i] + " " + losses[i] + " " + points[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter option: 3
[Enter N to end the game for a team or Q to terminate the program]
------------------------------------------------------------------
Enter the name of team 1: One
Enter W/L/O for match result: W
Enter W/L/O for match result: W
Enter W/L/O for match result: L
Enter W/L/O for match result: O
Enter W/L/O for match result: N
Enter the name of team 2: Two
Enter W/L/O for match result: L
Enter W/L/O for match result: L
Enter W/L/O for match result: O
Enter W/L/O for match result: W
Enter W/L/O for match result: Q
Team W O L P
Two 1 1 2 3
One 2 1 1 5
```

Comment: You dont need to input the number of teams, as it is upto 10, and doesnt state in the input, so would i just change int teams = keyboard.nextInt(); to 10?

Comment: Also to close the final while loop and get the results outputted, "Q" is outputted

Comment: You input the teams until "Q" is entered

Comment: Replace `int teams = keyboard.nextInt();` with `int teams = 10;`

Comment: int losses = new int [teams] //this doesn't work as when I change the teams to 10, it says that int[] cannot be converted to int

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know if it meets all the requirements.

Comment: One more requirement that u missed: "N" is used to move on to the next team, or enter the next team information. The letter "Q" is used to output the result or it means that you dont want to enter new team information and u just want to get the results

Comment: Isn't the program behaving this way? Did you run it or check the result of [**A sample run:**] posted by me?

Comment: Sorry I didnt notice that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I wish you success!

Comment: I am getting an error can u look at that? I attached a picture in my post

Comment: It should be `int[] points = new int[teams];`. Check my code carefully.

Comment: Does ur code works upto 10 teams being inputted because thats the requirement

Comment: Hello Arvind, one last request please, could you look at my code with an error that I get? I have edited my post. Also, I am not allowed to use break;

Comment: Alright...I've updated the code to do it without using `break` statement.

Comment: And how would I fix that error I am getting which I provided in the post?

Comment: Check the code carefully. I've used `for (int i = x - 1; i >= 0; i--)`.

Comment: Also for my understanding, why is that when you set exit = false; in the main and then to end the loop u set it to true and it works but when you initially set exit = true; and exit = false; to end the loop, it never works?

Comment: Programming is all about applying common sense. It makes sense to keep `exit = false` at the beginning of the program so that the program can run and change its value to `true` when you want to exit the program. Isn't it? This is how the algorithm also works. I hope, it's clear to you now.